# how to write output of a python script to html file

Tags: python, html

I am new to python scripting. The question is i want to take the inputs for a google search query in python script and write the response to a local html file. I have tried writing the python script for the same.but not sure how to direct the output to a html file. Can anyone provide an answer to this.thanks.

Below is the python script.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"

query = raw_input("What do you want to search for ? >> ")

query = urllib.urlencode( {'q' : query } )

response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query ).read()

data = json.loads ( response )

results = data [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]

for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's wrong with `file = open("output.html", "w"); file.write(my_output); file.close()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's build-in function [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for this